# Guardar y recuperar informacion del nivel de acuerdo a la experiencia

Tags: laravel, laravel-9

estoy trabajando en un sitio con laravel y estoy estancado en la siguiente funcionalidad.

Contexto:
Los usuarios por actividad en el sitio van ganando experiencia en el sitio web esta se refleja en la tabla de usuarios como experiencia o puntos por llamarlo de otra manera.

Tengo otra tabla con niveles o rangos y cada uno tiene un puntaje. Para escalar de un nivel a otro se requiren ciertos puntos que son diferentes a medida que escalas, es decir del nivel 1 al dos requieres sumar 10 puntos pero del nivel 2 al 3 requieres sumar 13 puntos.

Las dos tablas estan relacionadas:

**Modelo usuario**

```
public function level()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Level::class, 'id');
}
```

**Modelo level**

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

Quiero poder mostrar los datos de su nivel y su experiencia en la vista pero no hallo la forma de hacerlo correctamente.

He probado desde el modelo de usuario, buscar un level con el score minimo  que se requiere contrastado con la experiencia del usuario pero no he podido conseguirlo sale un error que debe devolver una relacion.

algo como esto:

```
public function level()
{
    return Level::where('min_score', '<=', Auth::user()->experience)
                ->orderBy('min_score', 'desc')
                ->first();
}
```

Me retorna que debe devolver una relación.

Asi mismo a la hora de guardar y comprrobar lara asignarle ese nuevo level me tiene un poco perdido.

Gracias

Comment: Podrias mostrar como lo estas llamando en la vista?

Comment: En la vista llamo $user->level->name  y me muestra la pantalla de error de laravel y dice  que esto debe devolver una relación . Pruebo con $user->level()->name y muestra lo mismo